# How to fix Gem Conflict Error with 2 versions of a dependency without bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rest-client

I am making a discord bot in ruby and am using the `rspotify` gem. `rspotify` has `rest-client v2.0.2` as a dependency while the library `discordrb` has `rest-client v2.1.0.rc1` as a dependency. When I try to run my code I get a `Gem Conflict Error` as both versions cannot be used. Is there any way to use both versions of a gem or somehow manually update `rspotify` to use `rest-client 2.1.0.rc1`?

I can upload a gem dependency list for all my gems but its pretty long. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I am not using bundler, instead I have installed the gems manually via `gem install <gem_name>`.
Errors From Console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from start-bot.rb:15:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rspotify (LoadError)
    5: from start-bot.rb:15:in `<main>'
    4: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
    3: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
    2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:217:in `try_activate'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1418:in `activate'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2302:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rspotify-2.6.0, because rest-client-2.1.0.rc1 conflicts with rest-client (~> 2.0.2) (Gem::ConflictError)
    6: from start-bot.rb:15:in `<main>'
    5: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
    4: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
    3: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:216:in `try_activate'
    2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:223:in `rescue in try_activate'
    1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1418:in `activate'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2302:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rspotify-2.6.0, because rest-client-2.1.0.rc1 conflicts with rest-client (~> 2.0.2) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use bundler? This is literally what bundler is designed for; it's a dependency manager.

Comment: But in direct answer to your question -- without further information -- it looks like you could downgrade `discordrb` to [version `3.2.1`](https://rubygems.org/gems/discordrb/versions/3.2.1).